# Is there any way to remove or determine the selected picture from photo library or camera?

Tags: jquery, html, ios

in Android there isnt any problem.. Opens camera directly..

[The problem is shown in this picture](https://i.hizliresim.com/4PlrD7.png).

I want to remove "Photo Library" Option
In picture "Fotoğraf Arsivi = Photo Library"

Is there any way to remove or determine the selected picture from
photo library or camera ?

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#foto").click();
    // BU ALANA Galeri'den resim seçilmesi engelleme gelecek

})
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 $("#fbtn").prop("disabled", false); //canlıda false olcak
} else {
 $("#fbtn").prop("disabled", false); //canlıda true olcak
}
```

Demo Here : https://jsfiddle.net/LsfzbdL6/

Answer (score 0):

You can give each of them onclicked function with [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

The function delete `this`, indicating itself on the function.